# PHP execute command and log output without waiting

Tags: php, windows, linux, cmd

I use exec() to execute command, either linux or windows.

How do you execute a command, linux and windows, and log the output without waiting?

I know for linux, to not wait for the output: `command* > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &`

And to log output for linux:  `command* > /path/to/log.txt 2>/path/to/error.txt`

How would you go about logging and setting it to background in one command? How would windows look like too?

Comment: You can exec() including redirecting output to a file, and then read the file via PHP later on.

Comment: The `&` at the end put things in background. But that does not work in windows, that's linux.

Comment: In windows, I believe you just use `start`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

On Linux you can do:

```
exec('command* > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
```

On Windows you can do:

```
pclose(popen('start /B cmd /C "command* >NUL 2>NUL"', 'r'));
```

Both examples disable output and errors, those go to `/dev/null` (linux) or `NUL` (windows) which means they are stored "nowhere".

You can replace these with valid paths on your system.

On Linux, a `&` at the end places it into background. On windows this is more complicated and needs [`start`](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) to invoke the process and [`cmd`](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) to allow redirection of the streams.

Comment: You could direct output to a file, and then fopen/!feof the log file

Comment: For linux, how would you go about logging and setting it to background in one command?

Comment: @user1105430: That *has* been answered in the answer. See the first line.

Comment: @hakre so I can use "command* > /path/to/log.txt 2>/path/to/error.txt &"?

Comment: It isn't mentioned, but you've to replace the entire `command*` (including the `*`) with your command. If you'll keep the `*`, it won't work.

Comment: Correct, the asterisk signifies a wildcard. Feel free to replace command with anything you like being mindful of relaxing control characters and etc.