# telling PHP to execute a windows command but not wait for response

Tags: php, batch-file, exec

Having read related questions here, I've tried various solutions, but none is working.

I've a folder of .html files to be converted to .pdf files with wkhtmltopdf. 
I've the following batch file which works perfectly

```
FOR %%i IN ("c:\websites\chronologicalLogs\*.html") DO C:\websites\staffzone\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe --margin-top 7 --margin-bottom 7 --margin-left 7 --margin-right 7  --load-error-handling ignore %%i "c:\websites\chronologicalLogs\completed\%%~ni.pdf" &del %%i
exit
```

HOWEVER, I have tried several ways to execute it from a php file after my html files have been created, but it always waits for a response... which I don't want.

I've tried
1)

```
$cmd="C:\\websites\\eyfs\\createPDFLogs.bat";
exec($cmd);
```

this starts the batch file but waits for a reply... no good.

2)

```
pclose(popen("start /B " . $cmd, "r"));
```

this doesn't seem to start the batch file

3)

```
exec('start /B C:\websites\eyfs\createPDFLogs.bat');
```

again, this doesn't start the batch file either.

I am aware of this one:

```
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$oExec = $WshShell->Run($cmd, 0, false);
```

but I don't have access to enable this in php.ini

Anything you can think of?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP execute command and log output without waiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250799/php-execute-command-and-log-output-without-waiting)

Comment: Perfect.... I'd seen a similar example but without the cmd /c bit, which is obviously crucial. Working fine now. Many thanks for the redirection.